# User Object Field Formula to count # of assigned contact

Tags: formula-field, count

I was hoping you can guide me to a formula WITHOUT using rollup summaries in the User object.
Note: I cannot create rollup summaries because it's not a master record detail.  It wont allow me.

Scenario:
In contact object, I have a field called RM where I can assign a user in that field.  The purpose is strictly for sales.  A user assigned to the contact is the salesperson.

Request:
Part 1: In the "User" object, I am looking for the total count of contacts assigned to that user.
Part 2: Once the record reaches 200 total, it will send an email.

What would be the best syntax for this?

Comment: DLRS for #1, Flow for #2

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done via formula field. Formulas are evaluated on every record access (so they do not store the previous "state") and cannot access child records (which is what you would need to do to be able to do this count).

You'll need to do this using something like the [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary Tool](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or through [a Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/developer-centers/flow). Since you're looking to do something after reaching a threshold, a flow is probably the more appropriate choice (because you'll be using that or a trigger to send the email anyway).

Comment: Note that the DLRS tool, as the name might suggest, allows you to get functionality similar to (and actually beyond that of) standard rollup summary fields when you only have a lookup relationship. It does this by making a trigger (and a test class) for you.

Comment: I guess I have to learn Flow.  Thanks for this.

Comment: Thank you for letting me about Flow.  I am able to get the roll up summary number,  Now I just have to be able to update the User field and input the total number.